# Scroll Element selenium webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Please provide an Help to scroll an Particular Element to bring to the view point to do some action:

```
<div id="divReviewForm" style="width: 100%; height: 463px;
     min-height: 300px; overflow: auto; float: left; padding-top: 20px;">
```

Inside the table its enabled a scroll bar , so I do the action for scroll down to bring to the view point, but currently I' m not able to do the above action.

Tried with following but still I failed:

```
((Locatable)element).getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just finding the element using webdriver should scroll the element to view.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divReviewForm']))
```

should work. Webdriver automatically scrolls element into view when it "finds" it.

Comment: yes sunita, you are correct, if we find the element with ID then webdriver automatically scroll and do the action, but, if any tooltip is overlayed with that element, then webdriver was failed to do the action

Comment: No, WebDriver doesn't scroll upon finding. At least, in version 2.34.0.

Comment: @DzmitryLazerka is entirely correct. WebDriver does not (and should not) scroll upon finding. It should auto-scroll only when you try to interact with the element via `click()` or `sendKeys()` or the like.